# Adjust display gamma value

Tags: delphi

I am looking into modifying brightness/contrast/gamma of my display i found an api whose purpose i think is this but i didn't had much success implementing it... here is the code

```
var
i,j:Integer;
buf:array [0..2,0..255] of Word;
wBright:Word;
myDC:HDC;
begin
    myDC:=GetDc(GetDesktopWindow);
    GetDeviceGammaRamp(mydc,buf);

   for i:=0 to 2 do
      for j:=0 to 255 do
        begin
            buf[i][j]:=buf[i][j] + 100; //if i don't modify the values the api works
        end;
    SetDeviceGammaRamp(mydc,buf);
end;
```

I will be grateful if you point me into right direction. Thanks.

The last error says : The parameter is incorrect

Comment: In what way does it not work? What is the error code? You have asked enough questions now that we should not have to ask this. Did you try GetDC(0) to get the whole screen?

Comment: The error code is ( The Parameter is incorrect )

Comment: Is that really your code, copied and pasted from the IDE? How and where is buf declared?

Comment: please edit the question to include this information.

Comment: @David: GetDC(0) and GetDC(GetDesktopWindow) are equivalent, AFAICT.

Comment: @andreas that can make no difference, alignment of word is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the array must really be a ramp, i.e. they map the possible R, G and B values to a brightness value. This way you can create funny effects too, but not with the routine below. Found something like this on the web:

```
uses Windows;

//    SetDisplayBrightness
//
//    Changes the brightness of the entire screen.
//    This function may not work properly in some video cards.
//
//    The Brightness parameter has the following meaning:
//
//      128       = normal brightness
//      above 128 = brighter
//      below 128 = darker

function SetDisplayBrightness(Brightness: Byte): Boolean;
var
  GammaDC: HDC;
  GammaArray: array[0..2, 0..255] of Word;
  I, Value: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  GammaDC := GetDC(0);

  if GammaDC <> 0 then
  begin
    for I := 0 to 255 do
    begin
      Value := I * (Brightness + 128);
      if Value > 65535 then
        Value := 65535;
      GammaArray[0, I] := Value; // R value of I is mapped to brightness of Value
      GammaArray[1, I] := Value; // G value of I is mapped to brightness of Value
      GammaArray[2, I] := Value; // B value of I is mapped to brightness of Value
    end;

    // Note: BOOL will be converted to Boolean here.
    Result := SetDeviceGammaRamp(GammaDC, GammaArray); 

    ReleaseDC(0, GammaDC);
  end;  
end;
```

Unfortunately, in my Win7 VM in Parallels on a Mac, I can't test his, but it should work on most normal Windows PCs.

### Edit

FWIW, I ran it in my Win7 VM and the routine returns `True`. If I use other values, e.g.

```
Value := 127 * I;
```

the routine returns `False` and

```
ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
```

displays

> The parameter is incorrect

Changing this to:

```
Value := 128 * I;
```

returns `True` again. I assume the values must form some kind of slope (or ramp). This routine creates a linear ramp. I guess you can also use other kinds, e.g. a sigmoid, to achieve other effects, like higher contrast.

I can't, of course, see any differences in brightness in the VM, sorry.

**Update:** But it seems to work for David Heffernan and I could just test it on my sister in law's laptop, and there it works too.

Comment: You don't need to and indeed should not call GetLastError when SetDeviceGammaRamp returns True. At least, that's even assuming that SetDeviceGammaRamp sets the error string, which the sparse doc makes no mention of.

Comment: +1 works a treat for me. Now I just need to work out how to get my screen's brightness back again!!! Excellent work.

Comment: @David: that's true. But apparently in OP's case, GetLastError does return an error ("The parameter is incorrect"). If I just clear the entire array with 0 bytes (`FillChar(GammaArray, SizeOf(GammaArray), 0);`) instead of setting the values above, I get exactly the same error message.

Comment: My point is that GetLastError is what you call when the function returns false. You don't need to call GetLastError to know it worked, Result is True and that's enough. Anyway, that's a side issue, you should probably edit the answer to say that Result is True. Anyway, I can confirm that your code works well and is the answer.

Comment: @David: It must really be a slope (ramp). The routine I posted creates a linear slope, and I guess others are possible, e.g. a sigmoid (for higher contrast), or something like it, but the routine seems to check the values for some kind of integrity. The "lowest" linear slope is indeed `Value := I * 128;`. If I use `Value := I * 127;` it also complains about an incorrect parameter.

Comment: @David: You are right, it is nonsense to call GetLastError when True was returned. But it seems to SetLastError when there is an error.

Comment: Works can't figure out what in the hell i was doing wrong but i am glad that works.Thanks Rudy

Comment: I guess you had values that wrapped around and "broke" the slope (values like 65530 + 100 --> 94).